# The use of chicken bones that have frost on them

Tags: food-safety, chicken, chicken-stock

I have chicken bones in the freezer that have frost on them. Can I still use them to make chicken broth?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you sure can. Frost, freezer burn, anything like that will have virtually no effect on broth making.